# Sending whole objects to meteor methods

Tags: meteor

Is it considered bad practice to pass whole objects to meteor methods and should I stick to just passing the ID, and then using the passed Id to fetch the document from within the meteor method instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main consideration here is security: if your method is expecting to be passed an object, a Meteor-savvy user can call it from the console, passing any object of their choosing as the argument, whether it's in your DB or not, thereby bypassing any DB schema/validation you have set up.  In order to avoid that, you need to be looking the object up in the DB in your server-side method code, which rather defeats the point of passing in the whole object rather than just the id in the first place.  So, in summary, pass the id rather than the object.

If the user *should* be able to call your method with an arbitrary object, then I'd argue that you absolutely should be passing the whole object rather than just the id as otherwise you're necessitating storing a document in the database purely so that you can call a method on it, which is ugly. However, I think that would be a fairly unusual situation.